# Classification of the terms according to the ranges of the years

Tags: word-choice

This has always confused me. While I'm pretty aware of who's infant, baby, toddler, the word *young* always *bowls me out!*

How the age is classified based on the range of the years? For instance,

> How many years a *very young* child will be? Any range? It's even confusing when you remove *child* from there - That's her! In her *very young* age. - What's the age now? In her adolescence? Childhood? Early childhood?

An answer with a good reference will be helpful. I hope it's not something an opinion based.

Comment: I think it's not so much a context or an opinion thing, but a *relative* thing.  What's *young* relative to one thing can be *old* relative to something else.

Comment: It's quite common to read this in stories...for example... *He saw a **very young child** and asked him...*  where the child is never mentioned with its age. But I think if **the child** is very young, how can someone talk to it? A child is okay to talk with but then very young child is how many years old? 1 yr, 2 yr?

Answer (score 1):

As @chapka says it is opinion based, but even more importantly (I think) it is *context* based.

A young baby may be only a few weeks old. A young child perhaps under five or six years. A young professor is perhaps below 35, and a young US president below 45. A young country could be less than a decade old in a news article, or two centuries old in a history textbook.

To speak to your specific example, it depends on who *she* is. If you are talking about a twelve year old girl, saying "when she was young" probably means when she was four or five years old. If you are speaking of a grandmother and say "when she was young" (more common phrasing than "in her young age"), it could be anything from her childhood until she was a young mother (another use for the term!).

I'm curious, does your asking of this question mean that in your native language, or others you know, "young" has a well-defined age range associated with its definition, regardless of such context?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry; it is purely opinion based. There is no universal, objective standard for what makes someone "young"; it's a relative term and therefore dependent on the perspective of the speaker.

There is a technical distinction among educators between early childhood and middle or later childhood; for this, the cutoff is around 8 or 9. But this is not a hard and fast rule and non-educators may have very different ideas.